# What happens to a thread blocking on a future which corresponding task has been discarded?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I'm using an `ExecutorService` to perform some computations on a thread pool :

```
@Override
public double predict(IModelInputData<EXTRACTER> modelInputData) throws PredictionFailureException {
    try {
        return threadPool.submit(() -> regressor.predict(modelInputData)).get();
    } catch (InterruptedException|ExecutionException e) {
        throw new PredictionFailureException("Error during prediction", e);
    }
}
```

The executor service `threadPool` has been created using a bounded blocking queue and a custom policy :

```
private static class DiscardOldestWithWarningPolicy extends ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardOldestPolicy {
    @Override
    public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor e) {
        super.rejectedExecution(r, e);
        LOG.warn("Discarded the oldest prediction task (too many tasks in the queue)");
    }
}
```

I made a test to ensure this warning was actually logged, and it is, but I am quite unsure about what happens to the threads that have blocked on `threadPool.submit(...).get()` when the corresponding task is discarded. It looks to me like they stay blocked, but this would not make a lot of sense. The behaviour I would like to see hapenning is an exception being thrown to interrupt the thread but I have not seen any.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, it looks like the builtin DiscardOldestPolicy just drops the oldest one on the floor.  The problem is that the ThreadPoolExecutor is holding a Runnable, and has no way of knowing what to do with it.  You could implement your own handler which does something useful with the task (making assumptions about the type of the Runnable).

Something like:

```
    public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor e) {
        if (!e.isShutdown()) {
            Runnable old = e.getQueue().poll();
            if(old instanceof Future<?>) {
                ((Future<?>)old).cancel(true);
            }
            e.execute(r);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, that's a possibility. However, this sounds odd to me that a policy provided in the API would have such a flaw. I don't know if it *really* blocks the threads waiting for the dropped tasks to return.

Comment: I just told you that it does, you can see the impl [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java#2001).  I based my example on the current implementation.

Comment: Yeah yeah  I have read the implementation also, but it was just too surprising to me, and still is. Would you be able to run a code that demonstrates that ? I have failed to do it, hence my question here.

Comment: Write* a code, that demonstrates the calling thread is blocked. But this is probably not necessary, you confrmed my thoughts. Cheers :)

Comment: Executorservice. submit () shallows exceptions. That's why you are not getting exception. You can see the difference if you change submit to execute.